# Java stops at thread's try-catch

Tags: java, try-catch, throw, continue, java-threads

I'm trying to write a code that will return my raspberry's IP when it's on the same network as my computer. The idea is for it to make a broadcast like Samba (Broadcast resolution is the closest to the original NetBIOS mechanism. Basically, a client looking for a service named Trillian will call out "Yo! Trillian! Where are you?", and wait for the machine with that name to answer with an IP address. Source: Samba team)

So here is the code:

```
public class GetIP {
    static String url; //global so I can access it after the threads are finished

    public class CheckIP extends Thread {
       private String url_test;

        public CheckIP(String url_t) {
            url_test = url_t;
        }

        public void run(){
            try {
                result = getHTML(this.url_test);  //result = the response from the GET request to this.url_test
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if(result <is what I want>) {
                url = this.url_test  
                System.out.println("Flag 1");
                <I'd like to do something here, preferebly kill all other 
                threads that are trying to connect to an 'unserved' URL>
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String ip_partial = <my computer's IP without the last part - ex: "192.168.0." , I'll hide the functions to make it short>;

        Thread myThreads[] = new Thread[254];
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
            String url_test="http://"+ip_partial+i+":<port + endpoint>";
            GetIP getip = new GetIP ();
            myThreads[i] = new Thread(getip.new CheckIP(url_test));
            myThreads[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 254; i++) {
            System.out.println("Flag 2");
            myThreads[i].join(); //todo add catch exception
        }
    }   
}
```

I can see flag 1, and I did print the first 'for' so I know there are 254 threads being created, however I cannot see flag 2. It never shows, nomatter how long I wait. Any ideas why?

Comment: @NeerajJain It is. That's how you instantiate a non-static inner class.

Comment: Never ever silently swallow exceptions `catch (Exception e) {

            }`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I made them silent cuz they were flooding my Console lol sorry, bad habit. But I did see the errors, they were all from connection timed out (no wonder).

Comment: @ScaryWombat [Yes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Your "broadcast" is silly. Have you considered [mDNS](http://root42.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/how-to-setup-mdns-lookups-on-raspberry.html)?

Comment: *they were all from connection timed out* **not all**  If you just wanted to ignore TimeOutExceptions then catch them seperately

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:`

You are executing the loop till **254th index**, whereas your array size itself is **254** which means the index present is **253** since java starts it's indexing from 0.

The first loop should also run the same no of iteration as your second loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 254; i++) {
                    /\
                    ||
                    ||
                    ||
      This should not be 255 else you'll get OutOfBounds Exception.
}
```

Comment: I thought that by starting at i=1 it would ignore position 0, and it wouldn't matter (because I'd not be filling or accessing the myThreads[0]) . I did that because on an IP adress (say X.X.X.Y), the Y = 0 and Y = 255 are never available (as far as I know), so as I'm completing the url with the int i I thought about the IP and not so much about the array. 
Such a stupid error, thank you for spotting it.  :)

Comment: In that case use the incremented value inside the loop instead.

Comment: I did that now. Thank you, Neeraj. 
I'll be deleting this tomorrow, as it may mislead people with a different problem clicking on this link. But thank you :)

Comment: you need not delete, it will help those people who might have similar confusion as you had.